# Large number of equations in an subequation environment. Avoid new page with preceding blank page

Tags: align

Can I page-break automatically a large number of equations in the same `subequation`-environment? I have to put them in an appendix and I cannot continuously change where the `align`-groups begin and end. As a result, the appendix starts in a new page, and worse, sometimes also with one blank page before it.

The align groups seem unnatural, but I have to create them in order for page-break to take place. Could this be achieved automatically?

```
\documentclass[11.5pt,a4paper ]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document} 

\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]

\appendix
\section{Long proof that nobody wants to read}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long } &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber 
\end{align} 
\begin{align}
\mbox{new block with a} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber 
\mbox{new block with a} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber 
\mbox{new block with a} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber \\
\mbox{long} &   \mbox{list}  \\
\mbox{of} & \mbox{equations} \nonumber \\
\mbox{which } & \mbox{I cannot suppress} \nonumber 
\end{align} 
\end{subequations}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble work?

Comment: `subequations` has nothing to do with the problem, which would be the same without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple fix using the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command placed in the preamble of your document.

Note that this command can't be used in `split`, `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat` environments. See [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for more information.

```
\documentclass[11.5pt,a4paper ]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\allowdisplaybreaks % <----------

\begin{document} 
...
\end{document}
```

[image]